# Spirng fails to create jee:jndi-lookup beans after migrating to springboot from pure spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere-liberty

Trying to migrate from pure spring to spring-boot. Some beans are configured in XML and are referencing JNDI objects provided by web server (WLP) such way i.e.:

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="executorService"
                 jndi-name="concurrent/workManagerTaskExecutor"
                 expected-type="java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService"/>
```

Application is packaged in WAR archive and deployed to WLP server. Now with springboot application is failing during spring context initialization with error message for above bean:

*Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain an initial context due to a communication failure. Since no provider URL was specified, the default provider URL of "corbaloc:iiop:1.0@492d7185007d:2809/NameService" was used.  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused):host=172.17.0.4,port=2809  vmcid: IBM  minor code: E02  completed: No]*

During migration no much changes were done, generally:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:beans-definitions.xml")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Tried with different springboot versions and it is the same. With pure spring - no problem..
Please any suggestion what does this error relate to. How springboot is related to it to how spring is fetching JNDI object..? :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is some nightmare, there was transitive dependency in classpath:

```
group: 'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient', name: 'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient', version:'8.5.5.13'
```

Later I found that for gradle build WAR task it was excluded (and I found it only after I have excluded this dependency :D):

```
war {
  rootSpec.exclude('**/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient-*.jar')
  ..
}
```

When switched to spring boot I have started to use another task for packaging and I did not notice that stupid exclude, who would know this stupid exception was caused by lib..

```
bootWar {}
```

Solution:
Exclude this transitive shit com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient dependency:

```
exclude(module: 'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient')
```

or declare it as compile only

```
 compileOnly(group: 'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient', name: 'com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient', version:'8.5.5.13')
```